# How to open a vertical split to the main view not just next to the current one in case of horizontal splitted viewport?

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows, split, keyboard-layout

I have 2 buffers on eachother covering top and bottom of the screen.

I want ot open a third buffer on right split but the problem is is I make a right split it will only split the top right or bottom right because i have already a horizontal split.

So is there any way to make a vertical or horizontal split on the main level while we have other splits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>There isn't one single builtin command to open the buffer *and* position it, I don't believe.</strike>

**Option #1**: *Well, it turns out there is. The `:botright {cmd}` style of commands (e.g. `:botright vsplit`). If @Mass provides an answer please accept that answer. I'll leave this for informational purposes as the Ctrl-W commands discussed at the end might still be of interest to some folks.*

---

**Option #2**: Create your own command with a mapping. For example:

```
nnoremap <leader>vr <C-W>v<C-W>l<C-W>L
```

I've chosen `vr` to stand for Vertical Right. It will open a vertical split to the right of the current buffer, move the cursor into it, then move the new buffer to the "far right" which will cause it to span the full height of the window.

In general, if you follow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> with one of <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd> it will move the current buffer to the *far* left/top/right/bottom, respectively, which means the buffer will fully span the window horizontally (if moved to far top/bottom) or vertically (far left/right).

Comment: uh, what about `botright vsplit`?

Comment: Uh, I didn't know about that. Why you talking to me rather than answering? ;)

Comment: So far this is the only answer until @Mass creates an answer im accepting this one